# dynamic width for h1 background

Tags: html, css, xhtml

My CSS:

```
h1 {
    background-color: #f7953d;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

My HTML

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

The background color is always stretched to 100% of the screen. How do I make the background color stop after "World" in the h1 tag, and not go all the way to the end of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H1 is by default a block element and so will span the full width of its parent container you want to make it an inline element (much like a span) in order for it to only be as wide as its contents.

There are 2 possible solutions dependent on your compatability needs

```
display:inline;
```

will achieve the effect your after however it does mean that whatever follows your H1 could appear on the same line.

```
display:inline-block;
```

Has the effect your after while still forcing anything following it to appear below the H1 the only downside to this is it can throw up some issues in IE<8 see [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding `display: inline-block;` to the CSS for your `<h1>`. This will make it use only as much width as its contents and still respect the `margin` and `padding` you give it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

HTML:

```
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
 <div class="clear"></div>

 <p>Elements after unafected by float</p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    background-color: #f7953d;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float:left;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

This works consistently (unlike inline-block which isn't supported by all browsers).

An inline of the element is probably not what you want since you require padding.

Comment: Clearing elements are a bad practice.